# In Hibernate can I swap from FetchType.EAGER to FetchType.LAZY without making any coding changes

Tags: hibernate

I am using Hibernate 4.3.11

In one class I use

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
```

To return a child collection

Having done some performance analysis I think this is causing me an issue, can I safetly revert it to

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
```

without having to make any other changes to my code, or not ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends: generally no, you can't switch safely.
Switching to this will create almost for sure some problems with `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`

This exception will be thrown every time your code will try to fetch some data, but then your entity is not fetched anymore and you have a closed connection.

ie:

```
public class Person(){
    Address address;
}
```

in this case, when you try to get `yourPerson.getAddress().getStreet()` you will get the exception above.

What you need to do to avoid this exception is rewriting your queries, and fetching the items that you will need to use into your code every time `yourPerson.getAddress().getStreet()` is called and needed, and avoiding fetching the address item when is not.

Since I don't know your class I'm generalizing, but I hope it makes you understand where the problem is.

When I said "it depends", I was pointing to hibernate option

```
<property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>
```

This resolve the problem of `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` , but it creates again the problem I suppose you had (slow and heavy queries).
This opens automatically the connection every time he needs to fecth the entities that have not been fetched when called.

You can find a very good explanatin about it [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-hibernate-enable_lazy_load_no_trans-anti-pattern/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can define `@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})`

So it won't fetch children data.

if you want children data in some method then write hql query for eagerly fetch Object with children

Suppose you have a User object with `List<Address>` in One to Many relationships.

```
"SELECT u FROM Users u " +
    "JOIN FETCH u.address  "
```